# Web-based browser GPS location

Tags: javascript, jquery, gps, geolocation, location

I am to build a website that could track the current location of the user. This is a web-base browser application that should work in both desktop and mobile.

I was able to see a [website](http://happyfresh.my/area) that uses this feature. By clicking the "Use my current location", it will prompt the user to allow to get its current location.

[image: get current location]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

Comment: Do you also happen to know of a plugin that gets the users geolocation without an alert being prompt? Wherein it automatically gets their longitude and latitude?

Comment: No you cant prevent the prompt, its a security feature cause not every user wants to share its location.